# Looking for a Video Program/Feature that allows smooth frame-to-frame skipping (when moving progress bar)

Tags: video, video-editor

Does anyone know of a program, or feature in VLC, that allows you to skip smoothly from frame to frame when dragging the progress bar? Right now, when I drag it in VLC, it jumps several frames.

Comment: Question slightly unclear? Are you looking for an incremental step through the frames. Usually that would mean using the keyboard to go to the next frame. Does it have to be a progress bar?

Comment: This isn't really on-topic here, you have a better chance if you ask this at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Gin-San Really? Don't think so, because people who interessted creating video also have to know how to playback.

Comment: Hmm ... I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1):

[mpv](http://mpv.io/) has very good real-time scrubbing using the mouse on the on-screen controls.

It also has seek-while-paused, and accurate-seek (decode-from-prev-keyframe) for seeking backward by 1sec.  Also frame-step backward and forward.  (controls: `,` and `.`).

It also has an A/B loop keybind, where you can easily get it looping over a part of the video.

So basically it has a lot of features that are great for reviewing a video frame-by-frame looking for problems, or stuff like that.

It's still in active development, make sure you get an up-to-date version for the most features and bugfixes.  I've only used it on GNU/Linux, but I understand it works on Windows and OS X, too.

Comment: Never heard of it, thanks peter - looks promissing. Do you using it for daily work?

Comment: Video is just a hobby for me (unless anyone would like to pay me to wrestle ffmpeg into doing what they need, or something...).  But yeah, I use it for all my video-watching, after switching from mplayer.  (I've always been a command line guy, but using it from file-associations in a graphical shell works too.  I do that occasionally when I have a directory of annoying-to-tab-complete filenames.)  I also use it for some of my audio-playback needs, when I just want to play a file, and don't need a playlist manager.

Comment: Makes sense, Thanks Peter - will try it. BTW: Who can I ask to pay you? :)

Comment: I'm open to freelance contracts.  I don't have a regular job ATM.

Comment: Hehe, sorry just a joke - thought we could write tons of spam mails to the ffmpeg crew, so they pay you :)

Comment: Heh, I should probably stop being lazy and finish up the couple of patches for ffmpeg I still haven't polished up for merging yet.  I do more using of ffmpeg than writing code for it.